# How to transpose and condense pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe (`df`) as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Query Strain": {0: "YAL001C", 1: "YAL001C", 2: "YAL001C", 3: "YAL001C", 4: "YAL001C"},
        "Array Strain ID": {
            0: "YBL026W_tsa1065",
            1: "YBR123C_tsa568",
            2: "YBR160W_tsa150",
            3: "YBR167C_tsa1074",
            4: "YDL017W_tsa880",
        },
        "Genetic interaction score (ε)": {
            0: -0.3529,
            1: -0.5317,
            2: -0.2163,
            3: -0.5053,
            4: -0.2082,
        },
    }
)
```

```py
Query Strain  Array Strain ID  Genetic interaction score (ε)
YAL001C       YBL026W_tsa1065                        -0.3529
YAL001C        YBR123C_tsa568                        -0.5317
YAL001C        YBR160W_tsa150                        -0.2163
YAL001C       YBR167C_tsa1074                        -0.5053
YAL001C        YDL017W_tsa880                        -0.2082
```

What I want to do is:

1. Convert `Array Strain ID` values as column headers
2. Then link `Query Strain` with `Array Strain ID` values by `Genetic interaction score (ε)` values

So the desired output `df` will look like:

```py
Query Strain  YBL026W_tsa1065  YBR123C_tsa568  YBR160W_tsa150  YBR167C_tsa1074  YDL017W_tsa880
YAL001C               -0.3529         -0.5317         -0.2163          -0.5053         -0.2082
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `pivot`:

```
output = (df.pivot("Query Strain", 
                   "Array Strain ID", 
                   "Genetic interaction score (ε)")
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

>>> output
              YBL026W_tsa1065  YBR123C_tsa568  ...  YBR167C_tsa1074  YDL017W_tsa880
Query Strain                                   ...                                 
YAL001C               -0.3529         -0.5317  ...          -0.5053         -0.2082

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```